# filter statement based on calculations django orm

Tags: django, django-orm

how can I translate query like this in django orm?

```
select id, year, month 
where (year*100 + month) between 201703 and 201801
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: why you need it if you can use date_range?

Comment: @BearBrown, because year and month are separate integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create an annotation, and then filter on that:

```
from django.db.models import F

(Modelname.objects
          .annotate(yearmonth=F('year')*100+F('month'))
          .filter(yearmonth__range=(201703, 201801)))
```

So here we construct an annotation `yearmonth` (you can use another name if you like), and make it equal to the `year` column times 100 plus the `month` column. Next we can filter on that annotation, and do so by specifying a `__range` here with two bounds.

Normally this will work for any database system that performs the operations you here perform (multiplying a column with a constant number, adding two values together), as well as do the `__range` filter (in MySQL this is translated into `<var> BETWEEN <min> AND <max>`). Since we use Django ORM however, if we later decide to use another database, the query will be translated in the other database query language (given of course that is possible).

Answer (score 2):

How about using something similar to this.

Did you try `filter` and `__range`

`Created_at` will be the field in your DB

```
ModelName.objects.filter(created_at__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Later you can do calculation in your view this is just a workaround.

If you want to run the exactly same query then probably you can run using.

```
ModelName.objects.raw("select id, year, month 
where (year*100 + month) between 201703 and 201801")
```